# Is there a first order formula $\varphi[x]$ in $(\mathbb Q, +, \cdot, 0)$ such that $x≥0$ iff $\varphi[x]$?

Tags: logic, model-theory, rational-numbers

In the first-order language $\mathscr L$ having $(+, \cdot, 0)$ as signature, it is easy to define a formula $\phi[x]$, namely $\exists y \; x = y^2$, satisfying : 
$$\text{for all } x \in \Bbb R, \quad x \in \Bbb R_+ \;\text{ if and only if} \;\; \phi[x]  $$

My question is : what happens if I replace $\Bbb R$ by $\Bbb Q$ ? More precisely :

> Is there a first-order formula $\phi[x]$ of $\scr L$, such that $$\text{for all } x \in \Bbb Q, \quad x \in \Bbb Q_+ \;\text{ if and only if} \;\; \phi[x]  $$

Said differently, I would like to know if the set of the positive rationals is [definable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_set) in that language. Related questions are, for instance : [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221633/definability-in-fo-mathbbq-leq?rq=1), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40553/fo-definability-of-the-integers-in-q/).

I don't know if the $\scr L$-structure $(\Bbb Q, +, \cdot, 0)$ admits [elimination of quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_elimination). If this is the case, then this could be helpful ; see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/697577) answer.

Thank you for your comments !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. Every rational number $\ge 0$ is the sum of four squares. This is easily derived from *Lagrange's Theorem* which says that every non-negative integer is the sum of four squares.

Note that the formula we get is *existential*.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer ! That may be very easy, but I don't immediately see how you can derive this from Lagrange's Theorem.

Comment: Let $r$ be a non-negative rational. Then $r=\frac{a}{b}$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers, with $b\gt 0 $. So $r=\frac{ab}{b^2}$. Now express $ab$ as a sum of four squares $s^2+t^2+u^2+v^2$. Then $r=(s/b)^2+(t/b)^2+(u/b)^2+(v/b)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

It is a famous result of [Julia Robinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_Robinson) that  $(\Bbb{Q}, +, \cdot, 0)$ is undecidable. This implies that $(\Bbb{Q}, +, \cdot, 0)$ does not admit elimination of quantifiers. That the rational numbers are not definable in the first-order theory of the reals follows from this, but also follows from [well-known facts about O-minimality of the first-order theory of the reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O-minimal_theory)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You gave an answer to my "I don't know if the structure $(\Bbb Q,+,\cdot,0)$ admits elimination of quantifiers", but how is the part of your sentence "the rational numbers are not definable in the first-order theory of the reals" linked to my question ? I apologize if this is trivial, but I don't see how these are related. Anyway, I've learned something :-)

Comment: It was just an extra bit of information that I thought you mind find interesting in this context.